# Why does Python use ".0" to represent an iterator in disassembled byte code?

Tags: python, iterator, bytecode

Consider this example

```
>>> dis.dis("[1 for i in range(3)]")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x10d6045d0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x10d6045d0, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)    <------ Look at this 
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

There's a strange `.0` in the disassembled byte code.

By analyzing each instruction, I know that it represents an iterator `iter(range(3))`, but why doesn't Python use a more intuitive representation like `iter(range(3))`, since it already knows its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a variable name. The generated function for the list comprehension takes a single argument, which is given the normally-forbidden name `.0` to make sure the name doesn't clash with any regular variables. If Python had to generate more names, they would go `.1`, `.2`, etc.

The `dis` output shows `.0` because the `LOAD_FAST` instruction is a read from the `.0` variable. `dis` isn't going to go looking for the expression the variable's value came from; that would be a lot of extra work, wouldn't be possible in general, and would be less true to the bytecode it's disassembling.

Comment: Thanks. Does this rule only apply to positional arguments?

Comment: @laike9m: When the CPython implementation needs to generate a variable name, the generated names look like this. It doesn't really have anything to do with positional arguments.